# importxml converting string to int

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

After many hours I finally figured out how to import data from `<span>`...
Yet right now I've hit next wall and I can't figure out what can help me in this situation.
After using:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.bodypak.pl/pl/aminokwasy/5890-6pak-nutrition-bcaa-pak-400g.html";"//span[@id='our_price_display']")
```

As result, we have `79,00 PLN`, yet that is String and I can't figure out how to convert it to INT
For making everything easier cell where I'm importing data I will mark as `#XML =Value('#XML')`
don't work, same implemented formatting.
I also tried to export the result to another cell and format another cell but that didn't work either.

`=LEFT(#XML,LEN(#XML)-3)` leave me with `79,00` but still I can't convert it to Int.
And I'm quite stuck right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `split` like this: `split(str, separator, 0)` and take the first item of the resulting array with

```
=index(split(arr,","),0,1)
```

All together:

```
=index(split(split(IMPORTXML("https://www.bodypak.pl/pl/aminokwasy/5890-6pak-nutrition-bcaa-pak-400g.html","//span[@id='our_price_display']")," "),","),0,1)
```

The formula above truncates the string at the ",". If you want to actually convert to integer, use `int()` after replacing the comma with a ".":

```
=int(value(substitute(split(IMPORTXML("https://www.bodypak.pl/pl/aminokwasy/5890-6pak-nutrition-bcaa-pak-400g.html","//span[@id='our_price_display']")," "),",",".")))
```

Comment: It works with integer but not 'double' as in a number thats 55.67$